# How to dynamically add interface to existing Java class in Groovy

Tags: dynamic, groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I've added a `compareTo` method to the `byte[]` class using a [Groovy Extension Module](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Creating+an+extension+module). However, I'd also like to add the `Comparable` interface to the same class, but couldn't figure out how to do it.

I'm guessing that it might be possible to achieve using AST transformations. Or perhaps there is a simpler way? Perhaps by manipulating the expando meta class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this, via AST transform. AST transform is only applicable to Groovy classes when `byte[]` is JDK one.

Metaclass allows you to add your own methods and properties to class, but can't change java inner `instanceof` behaviour. So, you can't add interface to JDK core class, to use in Java libraries.

Maybe, you should consider to use wrapper class, implementing `Comparable`.

Comment: Yes, of course you're right. So AST transforms are not a solution then. It's not really a big issue, and as you suggest, there are simple workarounds. Just thought it might be possible to achieve this somehow... Thanks for answering.

Comment: If you decide to use wrapper, check the @Delegate annotation.

Comment: @topr You notified me. Maybe it's better to use `@Steinar`, to notify asker? ;)